# C# Connecting to Rest Service to retrieve information

Tags: c#, api

I’m relatively new to c# and working with API’s. I’ve created a simple windows form in VS and I’m trying to connect t a rest service to retrieve information based on a search condition (e.g ID number) and display everything in a data grid. I’ve been looking for examples of what I’m trying to achieve with very little success. The idea is to enable a user to enter an ID number inside a text box and click a “search” button which will then connect to the rest service and retrieve all the information related to that specific ID number and display it all in a data grid with column names. Is this possible? Can anyone advise me on how to establish my connection to the rest service?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900371/how-can-i-call-a-webservice-from-c-sharp-with-http-post

see this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Path1 is your connection:
The Class ApiResult is just a class with a List of ArticleApiModel.

```
 public static List<ArticleApiModel> GetArticles (int id)
    {

        try
        {
            var task = Task<List<ArticleApiModel>>.Run(async () =>
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    var response = await client.GetAsync(path1 + "/api/articles/",id);
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResult>(jsonString);
                        return result.Result;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            });
            task.Wait();
            return task.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I’m getting an error that says “ApiResult does not contain a definition and no extension method ‘Result’ accepting a first argument of type ‘ApiResult’ could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)”

Comment: So the ApiResult is a class I made where I have a list of ArticleApiModel. So you should make a class that contains a list of your model and then replace it with yours.